# Appropriate programming language to design music software

Tags: learning, language-design, language-features

I want to design a software for my musical instrument which is a rhythmic one (there is no melody).
All I want these software to do is :

1. make the user able to compose music
2. play what user has composed

for that purpose I need to record diffrent sounds of that instrument and match each sign with the appropriate sound .

Which programming language is adequate for this purpose ?

Comment: Have you looked at existing software that will meet your needs?

Comment: there is no free form with the performance I want it to have in Iran

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Read about these languages and decide which one suits your need:

[**SuperCollider**](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/)

> SuperCollider is an environment and programming language for real time
>   audio synthesis and algorithmic composition. It provides an
>   interpreted object-oriented language which functions as a network
>   client to a state of the art, realtime sound synthesis serve

[**Pure Data**](http://puredata.info/)

> Pd (aka Pure Data) is a real-time graphical programming environment
>   for audio, video, and graphical processing. It is the third major
>   branch of the family of patcher programming languages known as Max
>   (Max/FTS, ISPW Max, Max/MSP, jMax, etc.)

[**ChucK**](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/)

> is a new (and developing) audio programming language for real-time
>   synthesis, composition, performance, and now, analysis - fully
>   supported on MacOS X, Windows, and Linux. ChucK presents a new
>   time-based, concurrent programming model that's highly precise and
>   expressive (we call this strongly-timed), as well as dynamic control
>   rates, and the ability to add and modify code on-the-fly. In addition,
>   ChucK supports MIDI, OSC, HID device, and multi-channel audio. It's
>   fun and easy to learn, and offers composers, researchers, and
>   performers a powerful programming tool for building and experimenting
>   with complex audio synthesis/analysis programs, and real-time
>   interactive control.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably check out **[Overtone](http://overtone.github.com/)**:

> Overtone is an open source audio environment being created to explore
>   musical ideas from synthesis and sampling to instrument building,
>   live-coding and collaborative jamming. We use the SuperCollider synth
>   server as the audio engine, with Clojure being used to develop the
>   APIs and the application. Synthesizers, effects, analyzers and musical
>   generators can be programmed in Clojure.

There's a nice [video demonstration of Overtone](http://vimeo.com/22798433) being used for live-coding music and instrument synthesis.

Overtone uses [SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/) under the hood.

One of the nice things about Overtone is that while it provides an environment for music programming, the language used (Clojure) is a general purpose language. So you aren't forced to learn a new language which is only useful for the music parts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine sound with a user interface of your own design (possibly even your own hardware), take a look at [**Processing**](http://www.processing.org/). It's a media-rich language that's meant to be easy to pick up, and the culture that's grown up around the language seems to encourage beautiful projects. Take a look at [some of the things people have created](http://processing.org/exhibition/), many of which involve sound.